# How to select all rows in grid panel using ExtJS 4 without using checkbox?

Tags: mysql, jsp, extjs

I want to select all rows(records) from my grid panel and store it into database. I am using ExtJS 4.1.3,JSP,servlet and MySql and I also want to fetch all data from my DB and show it in grid using jsp ,servlet. I went through many tutorials but that solutions are not working for me. Please help.

Comment: so, you have the data in the gridpanel already? if so, you can iterate through the store with  mystore.each(function(rec) { ... }); and do whatever you want in the function.

Comment: I am entering data in grid and wants to store it in DB.

Comment: I want to send all grid data to servlet using Ext.Ajax.request() method.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just asked a design for your app from client side to server side basically :). Lets split down the problem  to pieces :

Lets assume you have a rest- endpoint setup which updates the data in your MySQL db . If not , you will have to expose a rest call backed by the servlet which basically takes the HTTP request params and stores the data to your table , but I am not going to go into details of that as its a completely different discussion.

For the grid selection and update issue , you need to define your grid first. As I am assuming that you have a use case of selecting multiple records . So basically, you will have to instantiate a Grid with the selection model of multiple rows , something like this :

```
     var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        autoDestroy: true,
        reader: reader,
        data: xg.dummyData
    }),
    colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        columns: [
            {header: '1',dataIndex:'1'},
            {header: '2', dataIndex: '2'},
        ]
    }),
    sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
        listeners:{
            rowselect: function(sm, row, rec) {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'foo.php',
                    success: someFn,
                    failure: otherFn,
                    params: { recToBeUpdated: rec }
                });
            }
        }
    }),
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    frame: true,
    title: 'test',
});
```

You can refer to the official documentation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel).